# How to use Expect to Telnet with multiple files that have lists and change passwords

Tags: while-loop, expect, telnet, cisco

I am new to scripting. Expect seemed to be the best for what I am doing. I got it to run through my device-ip.txt file list and I was able to have it grab one password from my other lists to login.

I am having trouble figuring out how to allow it to go through all of the file lists as it does with my device-ip.txt. I am guessing that it has to do with the while command. What I want it to do:

- Grab the first Ip address from the device-ip.txt to Telnet.
- Use the first password from password3-list.txt to gain access.
- For enable mode use the first password from enable-password4-list.txt.
- For changing the secret password use the first password from enable-password-list.txt.
- The vty and con passwords will be the same so they will need to grab from password-list.txt.

After all of that happens I want it to go through and do the same thing but on the second line of each of the file's lists and so on until all list have been gone through.

Here is my Expect script that works with just the device-ip.txt:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# ---------------- variables ---------------- #

set timeout 2
set argv3 [open "password3-list.txt" r]
set password3 [gets $argv3]
set argv4 [open "enable-password4-list.txt" r]
set password4 [gets $argv4]
set argv1 [open "password-list.txt" r]
set password [gets $argv1]
set argv2 [open "enable-password-list.txt" r]
set password2 [gets $argv2]
set argv0 [open "device-ip.txt" r]
set ip [gets $argv0]
while {$ip > 0 }  { 

# ---------------- telnet ---------------- # 

spawn telnet $ip
expect "*Password:" 
send "$password3\n"
expect "*>"


# ---------------- enable mode ---------------- #

send "en\n"
expect "Password:" 
send "$password4\n"
expect "*#"

# ---------------- configuration mode ---------------- #

send "config t\n"
expect "*(config)#"

# ---------------- password change ---------------- #

send "enable secret $password2\n"
expect "*(config)#"
send "line vty 0 15\n"
expect "*(config-line)#"
send "password $password\n"
expect "*(config-line)#"
send "login\n"
expect "*(config-line)#"
send "line con 0\n"
expect "*(config-line)#"
send "password $password\n"
expect "*(config-line)#"
send "end\n"
expect "*#"

# ---------------- write to memory and backup ---------------- #

send "wr\n"
expect "*#"
send "backup\n"
expect "*]?"
send "\n"
expect "*]?"
send "\n"
expect "*#"

# ---------------- exit ---------------- #

send "exit\n"
expect ":~\$"
set ip [gets $argv0]
}
 close $argv0
```

If anyone could help, it will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve my problem. Here is the updated script for anyone interested:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# ---------------- variables ---------------- #

set timeout 2
set argv3 [open "telnet-login.txt" r]
set telnetlogin [gets $argv3]
set argv4 [open "enable-login.txt" r]
set enablelogin [gets $argv4]
set argv1 [open "password-vty-con0.txt" r]
set passwordvtycon0 [gets $argv1]
set argv2 [open "enable-secret.txt" r]
set enablesecret [gets $argv2]
set argv0 [open "device-ip.txt" r]
set ip [gets $argv0]
while {$ip > 0 && $passwordvtycon0 > 0 && $telnetlogin > 0 && $enablelogin > 0 && $enablesecret > 0 } { 

# ---------------- telnet ---------------- # 

    spawn telnet $ip
    expect "*Password:" 
    send "$telnetlogin\n"
    expect "*>"


# ---------------- enable mode ---------------- #

    send "en\n"
    expect "Password:" 
    send "$enablelogin\n"
    expect "*#"

# ---------------- configuration mode ---------------- #

    send "config t\n"
    expect "*(config)#"

# ---------------- password change ---------------- #

    send "enable secret $enablesecret\n"
    expect "*(config)#"
    send "line vty 0 15\n"
    expect "*(config-line)#"
    send "password $passwordvtycon0\n"
    expect "*(config-line)#"
    send "login\n"
    expect "*(config-line)#"
    send "line con 0\n"
    expect "*(config-line)#"
    send "password $passwordvtycon0\n"
    expect "*(config-line)#"
    send "end\n"
    expect "*#"

# ---------------- write to memory and backup ---------------- #

    send "wr\n"
    expect "*#"
    send "backup\n"
    expect "*]?"
    send "\n"
    expect "*]?"
    send "\n"
    expect "*#"

# ---------------- exit ---------------- #

    send "exit\n"
    expect ":~\$"
    set ip [gets $argv0]
    set telnetlogin [gets $argv3]
    set enablelogin [gets $argv4]
    set passwordvtycon0 [gets $argv1]
    set enablesecret [gets $argv2]
 }
 close $argv0
 close $argv3
 close $argv4
 close $argv1
 close $argv2
```